# How to fallback Scala version for SBT dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have dependencies in my `build.sbt` that don't have specific builds for the Scala `2.9.0-1` I'm using, instead I'm supposed to use the build for `2.9.0`. How to configure the build so that it determines that without specifying the exact version for each dependency? For instance [subcut](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut) doesn't have a build for `2.9.0-1`.

Some lines off my `build.sbt`:

```
...
scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-tools" %% "subcut" % "0.8"
)
...
```

I'd rather avoid this:

```
  "org.scala-tools" % "subcut_2.9.0" % "0.8"
```

Something along the lines of specifying multiple versions it'd try in the specified order.

Comment: I’m not saying it is not possible but how should sbt guess which version you actually want to have?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Maybe I could add some secondary versions to pick unless the primary isn't available.

Comment: '"org.scala-tools" % "subcut_2.9.0" % "0.8"' this seems to be the only way now

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I've done:

```
libraryDependencies <++= (scalaVersion) { (v) =>
  val scalaVersionString = v match {
    case "2.9.0-1" => "2.9.0"
    case _ => v
  }
  Seq(
    "org.scala-tools.testing" % ("scalacheck_" + scalaVersionString) % "1.8" % "test" withSources,
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.3" % "test" withSources,
    "com.github.dmlap" %% "sizeof" % "0.1" % "test" from "http://cloud.github.com/downloads/dmlap/jvm-sizeof/jvm-sizeof-0.1.jar"
  )
}
```

Comment: In this solution you still need to know which dependencies support the primary version you're using and which don't, and use the single `%` syntax on defining those that don't.